# Rendering iOS storyboard file in maui

Tags: storyboard, maui

I am not able to render iOS storyboard file in maui after migration from Xamarin. Where Xib successfully render in maui but storyboard file is rendering anything

```
            viewControll = new ViewController(infoView);
            pageViewController.DataSource = new PageViewControllerDataSource(viewControll, infoView);
            infoView.CurrentPosition = infoView.LeadListViewModel.LeadData.IndexOf(infoView.CurrentItem);
            var startVC = viewControll.ViewControllerAtIndex(infoView.CurrentPosition) as ContentViewController;
            var viewControllers = new UIViewController[] { startVC };
            pageViewController.SetViewControllers(viewControllers, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, null);
            pageViewController.DidFinishAnimating += PageViewController_DidFinishAnimating;
            infoView.ActivePositions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
            this.SetNativeControl(pageViewController.View);
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Use triple backticks (```) to surround code blocks before and and after the code (each on a new line).

Comment: `but storyboard file is rendering anything`   Can you explain your problem specifically? Is there something wrong or something else?

Comment: My problem is that storyboard file in not rendering in maui without any error. I mean while blank screen

Comment: Can you add any code from csprij that you're using to bring the storyboard into the project?

Comment: You can check the  above code  but before that be first is this code
   infoView = (_LeadDetailInfoView)e.NewElement;
            if (infoView.LeadFacade == null)    return; 
            var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("CustomControls", null);
            pageViewController = mainStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController;  var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var vc = window.RootViewController;                  while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)                    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;

Comment: What's the version of your iOS, Xcode and Visual studio version?

Comment: iOS version is  16.3.1
Xcode version  15.3.1
Visual studio 2022 release 17.6.9

Comment: And could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Create project in maui try to add  iOS storyboard normally having only one lable into it. Check does maui app in iOS something on view

Comment: For this problem, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).